# Adding Social counter

Tags: 7

i need to show in my site the social media counter like Facebook fans count ...

its some thing like :-

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Share count statistics](https://drupal.org/project/share_count)

> Allows your Drupal site to gather statistics on how many times your
> content (and other entity types) have been "shared" with
> social/sharing services like Twitter, Google+, Facebook, etc. Also
> provides an API for other modules to hook into and provide their own
> share counts.

[Social Stats](https://drupal.org/project/social_stats)

> This is a statistics module. It provides data from various social media sites. The data which is saved per node. It includes data from:
>
> 1. Facebook : likes count, shares count, comments count & total count.
> 2. Twitter : tweets count.
> 3. LinkedIn : share count.
> 4. Google Plus : plus one count, share count & total count
> 5. Total Share Count : total across all available social networks

Comment: i install Social Stats but how can display in site ?

Comment: pls share what you have tried and what does not works..

Comment: i am now install this https://drupal.org/project/social_stats but i dont know how can show block in my site ?

Comment: any help to show this module to my site

Comment: you can try something like http://www.nextweblink.com/2015/02/11/social-share-counter-drupal/